# Dataflow XML to Bigquery using Dynamic Table destination feature(facing latency issue)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I am new to Dataflow and got stuck with the below issue.

**Problem statement**: Need a Dataflow job(Python) to load XML from GCS into Bigquery (Batch Load). The Destination table in Bigquery is dynamic and calculated at the run time based on the XML file name.

**Solution Decided**: Just followed the article - https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-load-xml-data-into-bigquery-using-python-dataflow-fd1580e4af48. Wherein there static table was used in BIGQUERYWRITE transform, but I am using dynamic table name obtained via a callable function.(Attaching the code reference)

**JOB Graph**:
[image: JOB GRAPH]

**Code**:

```
import apache_beam as beam
import argparse
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from google.cloud import storage

# List the gcs file objects
# ToDo: Use Apache Beam GCSIO Match Patterns To list the file objects
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = "xmltobq"
bucket=storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix="xmlfiles/"))
blob_files = [blob.name for blob in blobs if ".xml" in blob.name]

#Static schema
table_schema = {
"fields": [
    {'name' : 'filename', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
    {'name' : 'CustomerID', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
    {'name' : 'EmployeeID', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
    {'name' : 'OrderDate', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
    {'name' : 'RequiredDate', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
    {'name' : 'ShipInfo', 'type': 'RECORD', 'mode': 'NULLABLE', 'fields': [
        {'name' : 'ShipVia', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name' : 'Freight', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name' : 'ShipName', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name' : 'ShipAddress', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name' : 'ShipCity', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name' : 'ShipRegion', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name' : 'ShipPostalCode', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name' : 'ShipCountry', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
        {'name' : 'ShippedDate', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
    ]},
]
}

def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
 known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
 pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
 with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

  def readfiles(element):
    '''
    Input Pcollection: GCS Element Path
    Output Pcollection: (XML, Filename)
    '''
    # Simple XML conversion using XMLTODICT package
    # ToDo: Once specific XML paths are acquired, we can parse only the required fields
    import xmltodict
    import apache_beam as beam
    gcs_file = beam.io.filesystems.FileSystems.open("gs://xmltobq/"+element)
    parsed_xml = xmltodict.parse(gcs_file)
    return parsed_xml, element.split("/")[1].split(".")[0]

  def xmlformatting(element):
    '''
    Input Pcollection: XML
    Output Pcollection: A generator of Modified XML Elements
    '''
    data, filename = element
    for order in data['Root']['Orders']['Order']:
        yield formatting(order, filename)
        
   #def tablename(e):
  #     import re
  #    return "gcp-bq-2021:dataset4." + re.sub("[\s+,(,)]", "", a)

  def formatting(order, filename):
    '''
    Input Pcollection: (XMLELEMENT, Filename)
    Output PCollection: Modified XML
    ToDo: This is just to handle the sample xml, production code will be havin different
    formatting procress'''
    import copy
    import re
    order_copy = copy.deepcopy(order)
    if "@ShippedDate" in order['ShipInfo']:
        order_copy['ShipInfo']['ShippedDate'] = order['ShipInfo']['@ShippedDate']
        del order_copy['ShipInfo']['@ShippedDate']
    order_copy['filename'] = "gcp-bq-2021:testdataset."+re.sub("[\s+,(,)]", "", filename)
    return order_copy


  # Dynamic table name same as that of input xml file by adding file name as key in the dictionary and accessing
  # them in writetobigquery
  # ToDo: In Production code dynamic schema option will be included in the   Writetobq transform
  pipeline_data = (p | "Create GCS Object List" >> beam.Create(blob_files) | 
                "XMLConversion" >> beam.Map(readfiles) |
                "XMLformatting" >> beam.FlatMap(xmlformatting) | "shuffle" >> beam.Reshuffle() |
             beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table=lambda row: row['filename'], 
# A lambda function to return dynamic table name,
                                   schema=table_schema,
                                   
  write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND, #WRITE_TRUNCATE
                                   
  create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                   custom_gcs_temp_location="gs://xmltobq"))
```

**Sample XML File**:
[image: Sample XML]

**ISSUE**:
I am able to run the job successfully in the dataflow runner and move the files to Bigquery. But the time it is consuming in the **WRITETOBIGQUERY** is too long, especially in  ParDo(TriggerCopyJobs) step where
the throughput is almost below 1element/second

> **Instead of a dynamic table if it is a single table the job gets completed lightning fast.**

[image: output throughput]

> Is there is anything wrong I am doing that is preventing parallel processing.

> Machine type used: n1-highcpu-8.

JobID: 2022-03-09_07_28_47-10567887862012507747

Comment: What's your lambda that perform the dynamic routing?

Comment: Guess you are asking about `table=lambda row: row['filename']`. This function fetches the xml-filename that is an element within the xml itself and will be used as bigquery table name

Comment: How many file do you have? and how many elements (in total)?

Comment: A total of 1,280 XML files in GCS and trying to create equivalent 1,280 tables in BigQuery

Comment: And how many entries per file?

Comment: Number of entries can be said like, 22 orders items per XML file and within each order there will be 13 entries

Comment: Adding to the above comment, when we convert a single XML to Dictionary and load to BQ, there will be 22 rows and 13 columns in the equivalent bigquery table